# Archiving app using Xcode10.1 Automatic Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with " " target's entitlements

Tags: xcode10

> Automatic signing is unable to resolve an issue with the "AppName.app"
>   target's entitlements. Switch to manual signing and resolve the issue
>   by downloading a matching provisioning profile from the developer
>   website. Alternatively, to continue using automatic signing, remove
>   these entitlements from your entitlements file and their associated
>   functionality from your code. Then rebuild your archive and try again.
>   Provisioning profile failed qualification Profile doesn't match the
>   entitlements file's value for the application-identifier entitlement.

I'm getting this error when I"m archiving my app, I re-set my .entitlements files, but it still failing.

The capabilities that I'm using are listed below,

- Apple pay
- Associate domains
- List item
- Background modes
- Push notification
- Wallet
  This issues is happening just in Xcode 10.1, but when I archive with 9.2 then it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case I have to delete provisioning profiles. Here is how to do it.

- Open Finder
- Enable it to show hidden files (CMD_SHIFT_.)
- Go to ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles
- Delete the profile you wish ..